# Как сделать из 2 списков словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

У меня есть 2 словаря со значениями:

1)

```
a =  {'fields' : [1 ,2 ,3 ,4]}
```

2. 

```
b =  {'items' : [a, s, d, f], [s, a, d, f], [d, s ,f, a] и тд}
```

Списки из 2 словаря всегда по количеству значений соответствуют списку из 1 словаря.

По сути значения из списка 1 словаря я в дальнейшем планирую использовать, как ключи, а каждый список из 2 словаря мне нужно соотнести к словарю из 1 списка, чтобы получилось так:

```
{'1': a, '2': s, '3': 4, '4': f},
{'1': s, '2': a, '3': d, '4': f},
{'1': d, '2': s, '3': f, '4': a}
```

Крайняя попытка потерпела неудачу на следующем решении:

```py
a_and_b = dict(zip(a, b))
print (a_and_b)
```

Получается так:

```
{
  '1': [a, s, d, f], 
  '2': [s, a, d, f], 
  '3': [d, s ,f, a], 
   # и так далее
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, буду крайне благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно универсально без указания ключей вытащить все значения через `dict.values()`.

После чего собрать их в трех циклах: первый берет все значения по всем ключам из `for bv in b.values()`, второй все значения `for av in a.values()`, которые комбинируем в словарь через `zip()` со строками `for row in bv`, полученными в первом цикле.

```
a = {'fields' : [1, 2, 3, 4]}
b = {'items' : [['a', 's', 'd', 'f'], ['s', 'a', 'd', 'f'], ['d', 's' ,'f', 'a']]}

comb = [[dict(zip(av, row)) for av in a.values() for row in bv] for bv in b.values()]
print(*comb[0], sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 's', 3: 'd', 4: 'f'}
{1: 's', 2: 'a', 3: 'd', 4: 'f'}
{1: 'd', 2: 's', 3: 'f', 4: 'a'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Да вроде не сложно, если я правильно понял задачу.

```
a = {'fields' : [1 ,2 ,3 ,4]}
b = {'items' : [['a', 's', 'd', 'f'], 
                ['s', 'a', 'd', 'f'], 
                ['d', 's' ,'f', 'a']]} 
a_and_b = [dict(zip(a['fields'], x)) for x in b['items']]
print(a_and_b)
```

```
[{1: 'a', 2: 's', 3: 'd', 4: 'f'}, 
 {1: 's', 2: 'a', 3: 'd', 4: 'f'}, 
 {1: 'd', 2: 's', 3: 'f', 4: 'a'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример как это сделать:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3]
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(dictionary) # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял что требуется, то у тебя правильный способ собрать словарь, но их должно быть несколько -- по `b` нужно итерироваться

```py
In [1]: a = [1 ,2 ,3 ,4]

In [2]: b = [['a', 's', 'd', 'f'], ['s', 'a', 'd', 'f'], ['d', 's' ,'f', 'a']]

In [3]: [dict(zip(a, x)) for x in b]
Out[3]:
[{1: 'a', 2: 's', 3: 'd', 4: 'f'},
 {1: 's', 2: 'a', 3: 'd', 4: 'f'},
 {1: 'd', 2: 's', 3: 'f', 4: 'a'}]
```

Comment: Коллеги, всем большое спасибо.
Задачу закрыл)